# Trying to use taxonomy hierarchy in views to create a category based menu

Tags: view, taxonomy

I expected this to be super simple, but it's turning out to be seemingly and inexplicably impossible.

What I'm trying to do, using views I want to create the following output:

Top Level Taxonomy Term 1

Top Level Taxonomy Term 2
child term 1
child term 2

Top Level Taxonomy Term 3

Top Level Taxonomy Term 4
child term 1

Right now I'm just getting a list of all terms, with nothing differentiating child terms. Even just some way to identify something as a child term so I can use CSS to make it display differently than parent terms.